# How can i fix the Vscode error trying to install ionic@3.20.0 on mac

Tags: node.js, cordova, ionic-framework, npm, visual-studio-code

```
npm ERR! Darwin 20.6.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "ionic@3.20.0"
npm ERR! node v6.17.1
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! syscall access

npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic'
npm ERR!     at Error (native)
npm ERR!  { Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic'
npm ERR!     at Error (native)
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'access',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/mikrontech/npm-debug.log
mikrontech@Oluwoles-MBP ~ % node -v
v6.17.1
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: As per your console log, you can try to add "sudo" before your command so it's gives admin access.